# Simple Mongoose populate not working with find—returns ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

What I'm trying to do is very simple.

```
const jobs = await Job.find().populate("type");
```

This should populate the `type` field of my job documents, but it returns the ObjectId.

I've tried it with `exec` as well. Neither work.

```
const jobs = await Job.find().populate("type").exec();
```

Console logging `{jobs}` I get ...

```
{
  jobs: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId('65b3b0cc33619fac72436220'),
      type: new ObjectId('65b27b4e47c6514cc776d3b3'),
      date: 2024-01-21T13:17:00.876Z,
      users: [],
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId('65b3b0cc33619fac72436222'),
      type: new ObjectId('65b27b4e47c6514cc776d3b5'),
      date: 2024-01-21T13:17:00.880Z,
      users: [],
      __v: 0
    }
  ...
  ]
}
```

I've looked at the other SO answers to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my schema

```js
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

export const JobSchema = new Schema({
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    date: Date,
    needed: Number,
    users: [Schema.ObjectId],
});
```

Comment: Please show your schema, the problem could be there

Comment: i dont see a relationship to populate. where is the type schema

Comment: Populate is used to replace an identifier (typically an `ObjectId`) in one document with the the full corresponding document that matches the identifier. Predominantly it's for looking up another collection and pulling the documents into this document. Do you have a `types` collection that you want to use to switch the `Job.type` value for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schemas and model definitions should be something like:

```
const jobSchema = new Schema({
    type: {Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Type'} // this allows population
    date: Date,
    needed: Number,
    users: [Schema.ObjectId],
});

const typeSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  key: Number,
});

const Job = mongoose.model('Story', jobSchema );
const Type = mongoose.model('Person', typeSchema );
```

And then this should work:

```
const jobs = await Job.find().populate("type").exec();
```